# Full height layout with NSSplitViewController with a Toolbar

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

I am working on a text editor app that needs an inspector sidebar for special actions with the text. I am therefore using an `NSSplitViewController` to manage the overall layout. I want the sidebar to take advantage of macOS' new full-height sidebars. I already have an `NSWindow` with a `fullSizeContentView` style mask. And my corresponding `NSSplitViewItem` has the property `allowsFullHeightLayout` set to `true`.

Unfortunately, I am still getting this layout:
[image: Normal Height Inspector Sidebar]

Additional information:

- The Inspector sidebar is an `NSHostingView` with a SwiftUI View wrapped inside.
- When using the accessibility inspector, I can see that the sidebar layout is expanded all the way up, but the `NSToolbar` seems to be ignoring it.
- I need to keep both the title and toolbar

Comment: This blogpost helped me to figure out what to do: https://christiangiacomi.com/posts/setup-nstrackingseparatortoolbaritem-macos11/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to let the toolbar know that there's a split view divider by using a special `NSToolbarItem`. By creating a custom identifier and rendering it as an `NSTrackingSeparatorToolbarItem`, I was able to extend the line all the way up.

To make the inspector view background extend to full height layout, I had to use `window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true`.

This blogpost helped me to figure out everything: https://christiangiacomi.com/posts/setup-nstrackingseparatortoolbaritem-macos11/